# sed between two patterns where result contains a third pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I'm attempting to filter log files for xml responses, and using sed as below, it is fairly easy to find all the xml messages.

```
sed -n '/<element/,/<\/element/p' file
```

Returns:

```
<element>
    <id>12345</id>
    ...
</element>
<element>
    <id>54321</id>
    ...
</element>
```

However I have been unable to figure out how to apply a second filter which means only xml responses containing a certain pattern, such as an ID, are returned.

In the above example, how would I filter on ID to only return the first one?

Comment: Please add samples of input and sample of output in your post too.

Comment: What samples are needed?

Comment: Samples of your question input and output so that we will better understand your question then.

Comment: If that's really needed, then ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for doing s/old/new/ **THAT IS ALL**. All of it's wacky single character runic language constructs became obsolete in the mid 1980s when awk was invented.

```
$ cat tst.awk
/<element>/ { inElt = 1 }
inElt {
    elt = (elt == "" ? "" : elt ORS) $0
    if ( /<\/element>/ ) {
        if ( elt ~ /<id>12345<\/id>/ ) {
            print elt
        }
        elt = ""
        inElt = 0
    }
    next
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<element>
    <id>12345</id>
    ...
</element>
```

The main benefits of the above over the currently accepted sed solution are:

1. It doesn't require you to test twice for `</element`
2. It will work as is using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box rather than just with some seds
3. It can be trivially enhanced to add additional and/or different conditions for printing (or not) the associated element
4. It doesn't rely on any cryptic single-character commands characters, everything is clearly laid out using the algol-based syntax common to many modern languages.

For example, lets say you wanted to print the first element in the file regardless of it's ID rather than the one containing a specific ID. That'd be a trivial tweak of the above to:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/<element>/ { inElt = 1 }
inElt {
    elt = (elt == "" ? "" : elt ORS) $0
    if ( /<\/element>/ ) {
        if ( ++cnt == 1 ) {
            print elt
        }
        elt = ""
        inElt = 0
    }
    next
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<element>
    <id>12345</id>
    ...
</element>
```

If you want to print the 27th instead of the 1st element, just change `++cnt == 1` to `++cnt == 27`. Try modifying the sed script for such a trivial requirements change and you can look forward to a complete rewrite and having to invoke additional tools. Want to print multiple elements and/or other parts of the file not within element tags? Also absolutely trivial with awk. Hopefully you get the point.

Comment: Only quarrel with this solution is the hard coding of the id being searched for. Replacing elt ~ /<id>12345<\/id>/ with elt ~ idQuery, and altering the execution to awk -v idQuery="id>12345</id" -f tst.awk file means that it is more appropriate for scripting.

Comment: @Andrew I couldn't tell from the question if a specific id value was wanted, or the first element containing any id tag or just the first element no matter what it's contents so I just copied what the accepted sed script was doing so you could see the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You can group commands for your ranges:

```
sed -n '/<element/,/<\/element/{ /id/p }'
```

But, you should really consider using XML tools when dealing with XML, such as [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

In order to print the complete entry when searching for a specific ID, you need to accumulate the lines inside the `<element>` node using the *hold space*, if you reached the end tag of an `<element>` node, you can replace the *hold* and *pattern spaces*, match for your ID and print it:

```
sed -n -e '
  /<element/,/<\/element/H # append to the hold space
  /<\/element/{ 
    g  # replace pattern space with hold space
    /<id>12345<\/id>/p  # print if matching ID
    s/.*//  # clear pattern space
    x  # clear hold space
    b  # start next cycle without further output
}' input-file
```

You see, this gets messy really fast.

Comment: This solution doesn't work and produces an output equivalent to using grep based on the id against the output of the original query.

Comment: @Andrew I realized that you wanted to print out the whole entry shortly after I wrote the answer. Look at the second sed script which does what you want, I think.

Comment: I understand it is messy, but that's what happens when you get told "you have to do X in Y way". The files are on a server and are quite cumbersome to deal with, so instead of changing things such that the xml messages are logged in a better fashion, this is the way we MUST do it :|

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/<element>/{:a;/<\/element>/!{N;ba};/<id>12345<\/id>/p}' file
```

Use seds grep-like nature by using the `-n` option which turn off automatic printing of every line. On encountering a line that contains `<element>` gather up a collection of lines until the end tag `</element>` is reached. Now check the collection for  `<id>12345</id>` and print the collection if true otherwise the collection is passed over.

If instead you want a specific element e.g. the second, use:

```
sed -n '/<element>/{:a;/<\/element>/!{N;ba};x;s/^/x/;/^x\{2\}$/{x;p;b};x}' file
```

This uses a counter held in the hold space which is incremented on each complete collection and checked for a specific number.

N.B. The range operator `,` can be used as a flip-flop type command but in general the `start address{:a;N;end address!ba; commands on collection}` is more useful.